# Using Sublime Text 2 for Python 3.4 dev. Standard Libraries don’t work

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext2

Why Python 3.4 standard libraries don’t work in Sublime Text?
Running (example in *Mark Lutz* book) in myth.py in SublimeText:

```
import math
math.pi
math.sqrt(9)
```

and get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*myusername*/Desktop/python/math.py", line 1, in <module>
    import math
  File "/Users/*myusername*/Desktop/python/math.py", line 2, in <module>
    math.pi
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute ‘pi'
```

Do it in terminal or EDLE and all works fine!

Comment: In Python.sublime-build  `{
 "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/«
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming your file to something besides `math.py`. You are trying to import the `math` module, and Python is choking because it's trying to import itself, and there's no `pi()` function defined. If you change your filename to something like `py34_math_test.py` you should be all set.